# Erlang wont start. Unable to load emulator (beam.smp.dll)

Tags: rabbitmq, erlang, erlang-otp

I had Erlang 21.2 installed as I am using RabbitMQ (3.7.10), this is on Windows 10. I wanted to upgrade to a later version RabbitMQ (3.9.15), so I uninstalled 21.2 and installed 24.3.3. But after upgrading RabbitMQ I cant run RabbitMQ.

When trying to start I get the following error:
Unable to load emulator DLL
(C:\Program Files\erl-24.3.3\erts-12.3.1\bin\beam.smp.dll)

I thought this might be an issue with RabbitMQ and have uninstalled and reinstalled both Erlang and RabbitMQ multiple times now with no change.

I decided to try run Erlang manually from C:\Program Files\erl-24.3.3\erts-12.3.1\bin\ but when I run '.\erl.exe' I get the same error.

Comment: Maybe compile erlang version in your pc, and not use binary version can solve the problem.

Comment: My guess is that the download corrupted the Erlang 24.3.3 installer. I suggest downloading version 24.3.4 and verifying the checksum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking Luke's advice we downloaded 24.3.4 and ran the installer. We also re-ticked the box to install windows binaries even though it said they were already present.

Not sure which of those two things actually fixed the issue but after that Erlang started successfully.